# Add Ubuntu to windows domain

Tags: linux, active-directory

I am new to linux. I do not have *any* knowledge on how to do anything on linux. I just got a new machine and successfully installed ubuntu onto it. The first thing I want to do is join the domain the rest of the computers are on. How do I do that. I tried googling it but all the results assume some sort of linux knowledge and I have none.

Comment: to help answer, it might be helpful to understand *why* you want to join the domain. What's the end goal?

Comment: @Chris_K I want to install apache server and and be able to access it from other computers on the network via http : // linux-server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would pay more attention to Chris_K's comment on your original post than to how to configure Samba to join a Windows domain.  You do not need this system to be on a Windows domain, you need it to be in your DNS!  If your DNS is Windows based, then log into your DNS server and add an A record for the service in question (i.e. wiki.mycompany.com -> 192.168.1.200).  Then once you have the web server installed and configured users can connect via https://wiki.mycompany.com/.

Comment: Agreed. No need to have it in the domain. Just add a the DNS record :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit like asking how to drive a car without the keys. I'm sorry but you won't get far if you're not willing to learn how to do simple things.

Your guide should probably be the official help:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ActiveDirectoryWinbindHowto

When it says install something, go to the System menu, Administration, Synaptic Package Manager, search for the package, click the little box on the left, click install. Then click Apply and it'll perform all the changes you've asked for. Alternatively from a terminal, just `sudo apt-get install <package-name>`.

When it says `edit /etc/samba/smb.conf` press Alt+F2 to get a run dialogue and bung in `gksu gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf` and that will launch the default text editor as the root user with that file. Alternatively, from a terminal in text mode, `sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf`.

For any other basics, hop in IRC (server: irc.freenode.net channel: #ubuntu) and one of a thousand people will be able to help you out pretty quickly.

Comment: Thanks! and I am willing to learn, I want to learn, just in the process of learning now.